# DirectX11 How to CreateTexture2D from unsigned char * data

Tags: c++, graphics, directx, directx-11, texture-mapping

I have a function GetCamImage that returns the image from camera as:

```
unsigned char* p = GetCamImage(...);
```

I need to create ID3D11Texture2D from this data. How can I do it in DirectX 11?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what the format of the actual content in that `p` is, as well as the width, height, and stride. Assuming the image is an RGBA 32-bit format with simple byte pitch alignment and sized as `w` by `h`, then it would be something simple like:

```
D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA initData = {0};
initData.pSysMem = (const void*)p;
initData.SysMemPitch = w * 4;
initData.SysMemSlicePitch = h * w * 4;

D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc;
desc.Width = w;
desc.Height = h;
desc.MipLevels = 1;
desc.ArraySize = 1;
desc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
desc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
desc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
desc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
desc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;

ID3D11Texture2D* tex = nullptr;
HRESULT hr = d3dDevice->CreateTexture2D( &desc, &initData, &tex );
if (FAILED(hr))
   ...
```

Comment: Actually, being curious, since he his getting image from camera, is it better to push data to a dynamic texture (need immediate context), or just push immutable textures and release them when a new camera frame is received?

Comment: Interesting, but isn't it this model used in many games (most times to stream lods and terrain data), to allow stall free resource loading by doing immutable load in a low priority thread and disposing when not needed anymore?

Comment: Actually I created a question about it, since I think it should interest a few people : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29549696/texture-streaming-in-directx11-immutable-vs-dynamic
Your valuable input is very welcomed :)