# Texture streaming in DirectX11, Immutable vs Dynamic

Tags: directx, directx-11

We often have the case where we need to stream textures to the graphics card (in game case: terrains, in my case image from different input sources like cameras/capture cards/videos)

Of course in camera case, I receive my data in a separate thread, but still need to upload that data to the GPU for display.

I know 2 models for it.

- Use a dynamic resource:
  You create a dynamic texture which has the same size and format as your input image, when you receive a new image you set a flag that tells you need upload, and then use map in the device context to upload the texture data (with eventual double buffer of course).

  Advantage is you have a single memory location, hence you don't have memory fragmentation over time.

  Drawback is you need to upload in immediate context, so your upload had to be in your render loop.
- Use immutable and load/discard
  In that case you upload in the image receiving thread, by creating a new resource, push the data and discard the old resource.

  Advantage is you should have a stall free upload (no need for immediate context, you can still run your command list while texture is uploading), resource can be used with a simple trigger once available (to swap SRV).

  Drawback is you can fragment memory over time (by allocating and freeing resources in a constant manner (30 fps for a standard camera as example).

  Also you have to deal with throttling yourself (but that part is not a big deal).

So is there something I missed in those techniques, or is there an even better way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the two main methods of updating textures D3D11.

However, the assumption that the first method will not result in memory usage patterns identical to the second case is dependent on the driver, and likely is not true. You would use `D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD` if you are overwriting the whole image (which it sounds like what you are doing), meaning that the current contents of the buffer become undefined. However, this is only true from the CPU's point-of-view. They are retained for the GPU, if they are potentially used in a pending draw operation. Most (maybe all?) drivers will actually allocate new storage for the write location of the mapped texture in this case, otherwise command buffer processing would need to stall. The same holds if you do not use the discard flag. Instead, when the map command is processed in the command buffer, the resource's buffer is updated to the value returned from Map in `D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE`.

Also, it is not true that you must update dynamic textures in the immediate context. Only that if you update them in a deferred context, you must use the `D3D11_MAP_DISCARD` flag. This means you could update the texture on a worker thread, if you are overwriting the entire texture.

The bottom line is that, since the CPU/GPU system on a PC is not a unified memory system, there will be synchronization issues updating GPU resources coming from the CPU.

Comment: You are right indeed, actually this D3D12 page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn899194(v=vs.85).aspx confirms what you mentioned about write_discard and map in d3d11

Comment: Plugging a case study on vertex buffer resource updates using the same technique and ending up with a sync stall: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/removing-cpu-gpu-sync-stalls-in-galactic-civilizations-3